# How to import test cases from Excel to VSTS/Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, migration, testcase

I have a lot of test cases which are currently in Excel that I need to migrate those to VSTS/Azure DevOps. Can someone recommend me a good way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

This is a manual way but maybe it will be useful for you.
On IE or Edge. You can try the grid view on your test plan and just copy/past test cases:

1. In test suite select creation of test cases with grid view:

[image]

2. Copy/past you test cases and save edits:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works. However it would be helpful if there is a less manual way.

Answer (score 1):

- Install [Team Foundation Server Office® Integration](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=Office%C2%AE%20Integration) (Excel Add-In)
- Open Excel and go to Team Tab and then click on New List
- Connect to your TFS
- Choose Input List then click OK
- Click on choose columns so we get all the necessary ones for creating test cases
- The Work Item item is set to "All Work Item Types", change this to "Test Case"
- Click Add Required and you should have about 8 columns, then click ok
- Now you should see a slightly different excel worksheet. -Change the work item type on the first line to "Test Case" and it should auto-populate the defaults

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I tried this. In the screen where we select 'Add Required' as you had mentioned above, I could not find the field 'Expected Result'. Do you have any inputs on how to get 'Expected Result' column.

Comment: @SK The `Expected Result` it's part of the `Steps` (the Steps not required so just add it from the columns list).

Comment: Thank you. Got your point. Any thoughts on how I could read steps and expected result from excel as 'expected result' is also treated as a part of 'steps'

Answer (score 1):

I  searched for almost an entire week before getting this to work and there were no answers online so, I thought I would share.

1. Install the Test & Feedback plugin for Chrome. (*this may or may not be necessary but it worked for me and I have this installed)
2. Navigate to the *old view of the Test Plan.

   - Note: To confirm you are in the 'old view', a blue link in the upper right hand side that says 'Switch to new view' will be displayed.
   - Note: When you hover over the test icon in the left navigation bar, choose the option "Test Plans" not "Test Plans*". The latter is the new view.
3. Select the folder that contains the test cases on the left and wait for the Test Cases to populate in the pane on the right side.
4. Click "Offline Test Execution" at the top of the pane above the Test Cases.
5. Choose to export the entire Test Plan or entire suite of Test Cases, etc., and click 'Export'.
   ***Note: If you try to export the entire plan or several folders worth of test cases and the export fails, choose less test cases at a time to export.***

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload the test cases including the test steps using Microsoft Test Manager and which can be accessed through Azure devops.

If you guys have Microsoft Test Manager, please find the required information at the below link.

https://github.com/premboyapati/Test-Case-Migrator-Plus

Answer (score 0):

they added a new feature where you can import export test cases in bulk[image]

link to the new feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops