# Is there a way to import a test cases excel sheet to VSTS?

Tags: excel, import, azure-devops, testcase

I need to import an excel sheet where my test cases are written into the VSTS and manage it through DevOps. Is import possible, if yes then please help me how can i achieve this?

Comment: Check solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136232/how-to-import-test-cases-from-excel-to-vsts

Comment: You can also try this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136232/how-to-import-test-cases-from-excel-to-vsts

Answer (score 0):

There is no button to directly import your excel sheet as test case format in Azure DevOps right now.

The simplest way to import your test case from excel to Azure DevOps is **: Import your test cases from web portal by copy and save.** Note you must switch to the grid view first.

[image]

On the grid shortcut menu, you can add, delete, or clear rows.

[image]

Switch between Grid and List views using the View menu at the right of the window.

[image]

More details please take a look at official tutorial: [Is there a way to quickly add multiple test cases at the same time?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#q-is-there-a-way-to-quickly-add-multiple-test-cases-at-the-same-time)